# fql query in javascript sdk for getting facebook users in a particular city

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am supposed to pick the user ids of the facebook users who lives in a particular location or city.How could i do it in a fql query in javascript sdk?